# How to implement (Include) in Onion architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to get Company with its employees and this is my query

```
Executed DbCommand (87ms) [Parameters=[@__companyId_0='?' (DbType = Guid)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[CompanyId], [t].[Address], [t].[Country], [t].[Name], [e].[EmployeeId], [e].[Age], [e].[CompanyId], [e].[Name], [e].[Position] 
      FROM (
          SELECT TOP(1) [c].[CompanyId], [c].[Address], [c].[Country], [c].[Name]
          FROM [Companies] AS [c]
          WHERE [c].[CompanyId] = @__companyId_0
          ORDER BY [c].[Name]
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN [Employees] AS [e] ON [t].[CompanyId] = [e].[CompanyId]
      ORDER BY [t].[Name], [t].[CompanyId]
```

This is what I tried.

```
namespace Entities.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        [Column("CompanyId")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Entities.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Column("EmployeeId")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }   
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Company))]
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Shared.DataTransferObjects
{
    public class CompanyWithEmployeesDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; init; }
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public string FullAddress { get; init; }
        public IEnumerable<EmployeeDto> Employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Shared.DataTransferObjects
{
    public class EmployeeDto
    {
        public Guid Id { get; init; }
        public string Name { get; init; }
        public int Age { get; init; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }

}
```

```
namespace API.Helpers
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>();
            CreateMap<Company, CompanyWithEmployeesDto>()
            .ForMember(c => c.FullAddress,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(x => string.Join(' ', x.Address, x.Country)));

        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Contracts
{
    public interface ICompanyRepository
    {
        Company GetCompanyWithEmployees(Guid companyId, bool trackChanges);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Contracts
{
    public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
    {
        IQueryable<T> FindAll(bool trackChanges);
        IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges);
        void Create(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Repository
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        protected RepositoryContext RepositoryContext;

        public RepositoryBase(RepositoryContext repositoryContext) => RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;

        public IQueryable<T> FindAll(bool trackChanges) => 
            !trackChanges ?  
                RepositoryContext.Set<T>()
                    .AsNoTracking() :
                RepositoryContext.Set<T>();
        
        public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression, bool trackChanges) =>
            !trackChanges ?
                RepositoryContext.Set<T>()
                    .Where(expression)
                    .AsNoTracking() :
                RepositoryContext.Set<T>()
                    .Where(expression);
        
        public void Create(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        public void Update(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        public void Delete(T entity) => RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Repository
{
    public class CompanyRepository : RepositoryBase<Company>, ICompanyRepository
      {
        public CompanyRepository(RepositoryContext repositoryContext) : base(repositoryContext)
        {
        }

        public Company GetCompanyWithEmployees(Guid companyId, bool trackChanges)
        {
            return FindByCondition(owner => owner.Id.Equals(companyId), trackChanges)
             .Include(s => s.Employees)
             .OrderBy(c=>c.Name)
             .FirstOrDefault();
        }
     }
}
```

```
namespace Service.Contracts
{
    public interface ICompanyService
    {
        CompanyWithEmployeesDto GetCompanyWithEmployees(Guid companyId, bool trackChanges);

    }
}
```

```
namespace Service
{
    internal sealed class CompanyService : ICompanyService
    {
       private readonly IRepositoryManager _repository;
        private readonly ILoggerManager _logger;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public CompanyService(IRepositoryManager repository, ILoggerManager logger, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _logger = logger;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public CompanyWithEmployeesDto GetCompanyWithEmployees(Guid companyId, bool trackChanges)
        {
            var company = _repository.Company.GetCompanyWithEmployees(companyId, trackChanges);
            if (company is null)
                throw new CompanyNotFoundException(companyId);

            var CompanyWithEmployeesDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyWithEmployeesDto>(company);
            return CompanyWithEmployeesDto;
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Presentation.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/companies")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompaniesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceManager _service;
        public CompaniesController(IServiceManager service) => _service = service;

        [HttpGet("{id:guid}/details")]
        public IActionResult GetCompanyDetails(Guid id)
        {
            var company = _service.CompanyService.GetCompanyWithEmployees(id, trackChanges: true);
            return Ok(company);
        }

    }
}
```

This is what i get:

```
{
    "id": "3d490a70-94ce-4d15-9494-5248280c2ce3",
    "name": "Admin_Solutions Ltd",
    "fullAddress": "312 Forest Avenue, BF 923 USA",
    "employee": null
}
```

and this is what i want:

```
{
    "id": "3d490a70-94ce-4d15-9494-5248280c2ce3",
    "name": "Admin_Solutions Ltd",
    "fullAddress": "312 Forest Avenue, BF 923 USA",
    "employee": [
    {
        "id": "021ca3c1-0deb-4afd-ae94-2159a8479811",
        "name": "Kane Miller",
        "age": 35,
        "position": "Administrator"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with architecture but it does show an *anti*pattern - putting a signle-entity class named "repository" over a multi-entity high-level Unit-of-Work, the DbContext. A real Repository should *raise* the level of abstraction, not lower it

Comment: As for the problem itself, without the non-EF classes like `RepositoryBase` it's hard to guess what's going on. In EF itself, retrieving a company and all employees is as easy as `_context.Company.Include(c=>c.Employees).Where(c=>c.ID==45).ToList()`. If you don't intend to modify these entities, add `AsNoTracking()`. This works precisely because DbContext is a multi-entity UoW and the DbSets are the single-entity Repositories.

Comment: Thank you.... i have edited the post with the repositorybase

Comment: So it's a CRUD class. But its CUD methods do nothing of the kind. They just track entities in a certain state - entities that may already be tracked by the DbContext. What's the point of this class? It doesn't abstract anything, in fact you *must* know its implementation to know what to provide to the `Find` method.

Comment: I don't see how you received `_repository` in your `CompanyService` .

Comment: In any case, are there any employees? Have you tried using DbContext and LINQ *alone*, without the wrapper or Automapper? The empty employees attribute suggests that either no employees were loaded, or the mapping failed because ..... `Employee` isn't `Employees`

Comment: Just updated the CompanyService.... yes it worked and it was fine

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a repository, it's a CRUD class. The error itself is caused by a typo though - the `Employees` property in `Company` becomes `Employee` in `CompanyWithEmployeesDto`.

Change the property to employees. And consider whether all this code provides any benefit over :

```
var company=_context.Company.Include(c=>c.Employees).Where(c=>c.ID==45).First();

var dto=_mapper.Map<CompanyWithEmployeesDto>(company);
```

A real Repository should raise the level of abstraction. With EF Core you're already at the level of a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. There's no need for single-entity repositories. In the question's code, the actual Repository is the `CompanyService` class

Comment: Just for my personal undestanding. Based on the reference that author presented in the post, do you mean if we use EF Core, then we don't have need to create additional layer of abstraction (Repository, based on the author example) because EF Core provides this layer, is this correct?

Comment: There's no reference in the question. If you want references, check [Repositories and Unit-of-Work Don't Mix](https://robconery.com/databases/repositories-on-top-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) by Rob Connery, [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) by Gunnar Peipman and [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) by Ayende (Oren Eini) who, at the time, was the maintainer of NHibernate